# How to save canvas drawing and display it when the button is clicked

Tags: android, eclipse, canvas, save

hey i am trying to create android app where i can draw on canvas with two buttons on the bottom 
i managed to get the drawing to work however right now i need to add two buttons(one is for saving the drawing canvas into database (Sqlite if possible) or bitmap and the other one to import the image from the sqlite and display it into the graphicview)

right now i have no idea what code i have to put into it to make the save and display button works so please help me with the code and thank you for your time :)

here is my code at the moment (the graphic drawing works fine and now i need the code for the save and display button as well as what ive missed in the graphicview.java and MainActivity.java)

**GraphicsView.java**

```
package org.example.graphics;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Path.Direction;
import android.view.*;

public class GraphicsView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

public GraphicsView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
}

ArrayList<MyPoint> arrOfPoints=new ArrayList<MyPoint>();

class MyPoint
{
    float x, y;
}
float downx, downy;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Drawing commands go here

    Paint rectPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    rectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    rectPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, 100, 100), 10, 10, rectPaint);

    rectPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    rectPaint.setAlpha(40);
    canvas.drawCircle(300, 300, 200, rectPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(new RectF(40, 40, 200, 200), rectPaint);
    Paint textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
            | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    canvas.drawText("Hello there!", 200, 200, textPaint);

    canvas.drawText("You clicked on " + downx + "," + downy, 200, 600,
            textPaint);
        for(int i=0;i<arrOfPoints.size();i++)
                {
                    canvas.drawCircle(arrOfPoints.get(i).x, arrOfPoints.get(i).y, 20, rectPaint);
                }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    int action = arg1.getAction();
    MyPoint p=null;
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        downx = arg1.getX();
        downy = arg1.getY();

        p=new MyPoint();
        p.x=arg1.getX();p.y=arg1.getY();

        arrOfPoints.add(p);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        downx = arg1.getX();
        downy = arg1.getY();
        p=new MyPoint();
        p.x=arg1.getX();p.y=arg1.getY();
        arrOfPoints.add(p);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package org.example.graphics;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Path.Direction;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new GraphicsView(this));
}
```

**main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/background">

 <org.example.graphics.GraphicsView
   android:id="@+id/graphics"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="341dp" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/ChoosePictureButton"/>
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Choose Picture"

 <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save Picture" android:id="@+id/SavePictureButton"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml is still at default because i havent edit anything in it yet

Comment: Save the canvas as PNG file, then load it via your imageView

Comment: where do i add the code for png file? in the mainactivity or graphicsview?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your save button click listener.

```
int canvasWidth = 500;
int canvasHeight = 500;
View v = new GraphicsView(MainActivity.this);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
v.draw(canvas);

//now bitmap has your canvas image

//set it to your ImageView
yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

//or save to sdcard
File dir = new File("/sdcard/yourAppFolder/");
if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
File outputFile = new File(dir, "image.jpg");
OutputStream fout = null;
fout = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fout);
fout.flush();
fout.close();
```

Comment: so do i have to add the method for save button inside the MainActivity.java? sorry im still new to android and i havent added anything into the MainActivity.java yet

Comment: @KopArtist: yes you need to add it in MainActivity.java

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply here is my new code inside the MainActivity.java. im pretty sure it isnt correct could you tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: @KopArtist: you need to declare button and then you can add click listener to it, checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372104/best-practice-for-defining-button-events-in-android

Comment: i fixed my code in MainActivity.java to this [http://tinypic.com/r/2gtn720/8] is this the correct code? how come i still got the error on the "v"

Comment: @KopArtist: just rename v to v1, because you already have variable named v.

Comment: i keep getting this error [http://tinypic.com/r/2z5qk4m/8] which one should i click?

Comment: @KopArtist: remove implements from MainActivity and try again

Comment: this is what happen when i removed the implements fromm the MainAcitivty [http://tinypic.com/r/2ptyuzt/8]

Comment: @KopArtist: remove onClickListener also

Comment: @KopArtist: I think you need to learn some basics of android, you can get some help here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html

Comment: still get this error, should i remove any part of the code? [http://tinypic.com/r/1fvmth/8]

Comment: @KopArtist: I suggest you to try with fresh project and try again in that new project.