# Handle onClick on Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick

I have a fragment which has 4 images(on a Linear Layout) - based on the image clicked, the background should change. I can implement onClick listener for each image and change the background based on the image ID clicked. I wanted to understand if there is a better procedure. I read here([Best practice for defining button events in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372104/best-practice-for-defining-button-events-in-android))  that I can I can register onClick in the XML and handle it. But If I do it that way, it looks for a call back method in activity. But I want it to deal it in Fragments itself. Is there a better way for it?

Comment: In order to determine if there is a better way, it would be helpful for you to provide the code you currently have. Then people can suggest changes to improve it.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onClick method use something like:

```
if (v.getId() == myItem.getId()) {
    // do something
} else if (v.getId() == myItem2.getId()) {
    // do something else
} else if (v.getId() == myItem3.getId()) {
    // do something else
}
```