# Error at opening another Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm simply trying to open another `Activity` when I click to `btnFemale` `Button` and `btnMale` `Button`.Now `btnfemale` `Button` is works well but `btnMale` `Button` doesnt work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button BtnFemale = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFemale);
        final Button BtnMale = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMale);

        BtnFemale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

  BtnMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityThree.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    });
    }
}
```

Comment: get it out of the first listener!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create seperate listener, not one inside another

```
BtnFemale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});

BtnMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityThree.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

You are adding listener of `BtnMale` when clicking on `BtnFemale`.

Comment: Add some description as well

Comment: I pasted this code but anyway when I run the app and click btnMale app stops itself.

Comment: @Grenade its another question, possible answers 1) may be you did not declared your activity in manifest. 2) `btnMale` might not be available in your activity. 3) There is some issues with your `ActivityThree` activity

Comment: I checked that my activity in manifest wasnt written well so I corrected it and now works.Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

change your code to

```
BtnFemale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

BtnMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityThree.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Button BtnFemale = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFemale);
        final Button BtnMale = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMale);

        BtnFemale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            });


                BtnMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityThree.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Correct your code braces are not properly managed

Answer (score 1):

Create separate listeners for the buttons.
Please follow the below link.
[Best practice for defining button events in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372104/best-practice-for-defining-button-events-in-android)

```
 BtnFemale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });



            BtnMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityThree.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                });
```