# When to implement Activity-wide click event?

Tags: android, onclick

I usually  implement click event bound to a certain visual element, like

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
```

Often I see examples where they use Activity-wide onclick (implementing View.OnClickListener) and then they do not create `View.OnClickListener` for each element but rather just pass `this`, like

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener { 

    //...

    someUIElement.setOnClickListener(this);

    public void onClick(View view) {
       //TODO implement this
    }
}
```

When should I use such Activity-wide OnClick events? Are both ways the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please check may be helpful

[How to handle button clicks using the XML onClick within Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html