# Fragments onClick method in fragment element

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-3.0-honeycomb

I read quite some articles about fragments, but I am still confused about how to do what.

I have a MainActivity, which displays two fragments side by side. In one of the fragments I have a button and defined in the fragments layout XML for the button

```
android:onClick="buttonClicked"
```

Now I want to implement that method

```
public void buttonClicked(View view)
```

I would have assumed that this has to be implemented in FragmentA.java and not in MainActivity.java. But it only works if that method is implemented in MainActivity.java. Why is that? To me that doesn't make sense. Pre Honeycomb a method belonging to one activity stayed in that activity, now on a tablet I am merging many activities to one MainActivity and all the different methods are merged? Whatever do you put for example in FragmentA.java then? What if you have to start you an own activity because this app runs on a handheld, then the onClick method has not to be in the MainActivity but in the Activity which needs to be called then. I am pretty confused at the moment...

Comment: Might be because the fragment layout xml is inflated using the main activities context. Lets see what others will answer.

Comment: What do you mean "it only works if the method is implemented in `MainActivity.java`". Do you get an error, or does your code simply not give you the result you are expecting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570575/onclick-inside-fragment-called-on-activity
Here same question is answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the specific problem is, but maybe this will help.

From the Android documentation on `Fragment`s:

> You should design each fragment as a modular and reusable activity component. That is, because each fragment defines its own layout and its own behavior with its own lifecycle callbacks, you can include one fragment in multiple activities, so you should design for reuse and avoid directly manipulating one fragment from another fragment.

That is, you should never manipulate a fragment from another fragment; rather, this should be done through the underlying Activity. Read the "Creating event callbacks to the activity" section in this [**article**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) for more information (it's important stuff!!).

On the other hand, if you want the button to perform an action within the `Fragment` itself (i.e. if you wanted a `Button` click to change the text of a `TextView` within the Fragment), you should implement this in the `Fragment`, not the `Activity` (this is because the resulting behavior is contained within the `Fragment` and has nothing to do with the parent `Activity`).

Leave a comment and I can clarify if my post is confusing... I only recently began to understand `Fragment`'s myself :).

Comment: I can confirm that AndyAndroid's concern is well-founded. And I have the same problem with a TabHost & multiple FragmentActivity's.  Basically, my onClick method that is called in the layout is expecting that method to be defined in the TabHost class, NOT the Fragment.  Hence the big problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading correctly, this is marked as answer, but how do I make `onClick` listener inside fragment without resorting to creating listeners programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I guess it is related to hierarchy of android context structure.
Activity is host of all child views and hence you can say fragment is actually using its host's context.And that's why when you use onClick with fragment system always searches it in Host activity of fragment.

Check it on.
[Android developer onClick attribute description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick)

I haven't checked one thing but you could put a test.
By providing implementation in host activity rather than in fragment,but use onClick on layout file of fragment.It should call parent's method.