# Android Fragment onClick button Method

Tags: android, android-button

I'm trying to invoke the method in my onClick (View v) XML, but does not work with Fragment. This is the error.

```
01-17 12:38:36.840: E/AndroidRuntime(4171): java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Could not find a method insertIntoDb(View) in the activity class main.MainActivity 
for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btn_conferma'
```

Java code:

```
public void insertIntoDb(View v) {
...
}
```

XML:

```
<Button
        android:id="@id/btn_conferma"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/bottoni"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:onClick="insertIntoDb"
        android:text="SALVA"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: Please post more of the stacktrace and relevant code

Comment: As stated in here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents, "The Activity hosting the layout must then implement the corresponding method.". In your case, you implemented corresponding method in your fragment. Because of this, it throws IllegalStateException because it couldn't find the corresponding method in the activity. Maybe, you can apply a trick as shown in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/6271637/2515815

Comment: The method insertIntoDb(View) must be in main.MainActivity and not in Fragment class.

Comment: best solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570575/onclick-inside-fragment-called-on-activity/27289827#27289827

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle button clicks using the XML onClick within Fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments)

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Your activity must have

```
public void insertIntoDb(View v) {
...
}
```

not Fragment .

If you don't want the above in activity. initialize button in fragment and set listener to the same.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_conferma" // + missing
```

Then

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rssitem_detail,
    container, false);
   Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_conferma);
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v)
             {
                // do something
             } 
   }); 
   return view;
}
```

Comment: This causes the fragment to crash in my project which uses API 21. Any alternate fixes/suggestions?

Comment: @DarthCoder i don't think so. You need to present the code. It may not be related to this code posted here

Comment: @Sanu nothing to do with lollipop pre lollipop. post another question with details..

Comment: The click event is never triggered when I do as the answer above.

Comment: I am a bit surprised by the comments above. No offense, but just saying "it doesn't work" without posting any details is very unprofessional... And as for me, "it just works".

Comment: This will work for you if you are using kotlin.
val button = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.btnAddCustomer)
        button.setOnClickListener( {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })

Answer (score 19):

Another option may be to have your fragment implement View.OnClickListener and override onClick(View v) within your fragment. If you need to have your fragment talk to the activity simply add an interface with desired method(s) and have the activity implement the interface and override its method(s).

```
public class FragName extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener { 
    public FragmentCommunicator fComm;
    public ImageButton res1, res2;
    int c;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            fComm = (FragmentCommunicator) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement FragmentCommunicator");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        res1 = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.responseButton1);
        res1.setOnClickListener(this);
        res2 = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.responseButton2);
        res2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(final View v) { //check for what button is pressed
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.responseButton1:
                  c *= fComm.fragmentContactActivity(2);
                  break;
                case R.id.responseButton2:
                  c *= fComm.fragmentContactActivity(4);
                  break;
                default:
                  c *= fComm.fragmentContactActivity(100);
                  break;
    }
    public interface FragmentCommunicator{
        public int fragmentContactActivity(int b);
    }



public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements FragName.FragmentCommunicator{
    int a = 10;
    //variable a is update by fragment. ex. use to change textview or whatever else you'd like.

    public int fragmentContactActivity(int b) {
        //update info on activity here
        a += b;
        return a;
    }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: I do this all the time, but still think it's ugly

Comment: I did too at first but now it's become almost second hand; plus it actually helped in more complex apps but for something basic it appears to be overkill.

Comment: @cjayem13, can you please elaborate "why is it an overkill"?

Answer (score 10):

This is not an issue, this is a design of Android.  See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks/):

> You should design each fragment as a modular and reusable activity
>   component. That is, because each fragment defines its own layout and
>   its own behavior with its own lifecycle callbacks, you can include one
>   fragment in multiple activities, so you should design for reuse and
>   avoid directly manipulating one fragment from another fragment.

A possible workaround would be to do something like this in your MainActivity:

```
Fragment someFragment;    

...onCreate etc instantiating your fragments

public void myClickMethod(View v){
    someFragment.myClickMethod(v);
}
```

and then in your Fragment class:

```
public void myClickMethod(View v){
    switch(v.getid()){
       // Your code here
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

For Kotlin users:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?, 
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?) : View?
{
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    var myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    var btn_test = myView.btn_test as Button
    btn_test.setOnClickListener {
        textView.text = "hunny home fragment"
    }

    return myView
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The others have already said that methods in onClick are searched in activities, not fragments. Nevertheless, if you really want it, it *is* possible.

Basically, each view has a tag (probably null). We set the root view's tag to the fragment that inflated that view. Then, it is easy to search the view parents and retrieve the fragment containing the clicked button. Now, we find out the method name and use reflection to call the same method from the retrieved fragment. Easy!

*in a class that extends `Fragment`:*

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_id, container, false);

    OnClickFragments.registerTagFragment(rootView, this); // <========== !!!!!

    return rootView;
}

public void onButtonSomething(View v) {
    Log.d("~~~","~~~ MyFragment.onButtonSomething");
    // whatever
}
```

*all activities are derived from the same ButtonHandlingActivity:*

```
public class PageListActivity extends ButtonHandlingActivity
```

*ButtonHandlingActivity.java:*

```
public class ButtonHandlingActivity extends Activity {

    public void onButtonSomething(View v) {
        OnClickFragments.invokeFragmentButtonHandlerNoExc(v);
//or, if you want to handle exceptions:
//      try {
//          OnClickFragments.invokeFragmentButtonHandler(v);
//      } catch ...
    }

}
```

It has to define methods for all xml onClick handlers.

*com/example/customandroid/OnClickFragments.java:*

```
package com.example.customandroid;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;

public abstract class OnClickFragments {
    public static class FragmentHolder {
        Fragment fragment;
        public FragmentHolder(Fragment fragment) {
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }
    }
    public static Fragment getTagFragment(View view) {
        for (View v = view; v != null; v = (v.getParent() instanceof View) ? (View)v.getParent() : null) {
            Object tag = v.getTag();
            if (tag != null && tag instanceof FragmentHolder) {
                return ((FragmentHolder)tag).fragment;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static String getCallingMethodName(int callsAbove) {
        Exception e = new Exception();
        e.fillInStackTrace();
        String methodName = e.getStackTrace()[callsAbove+1].getMethodName();
        return methodName;
    }
    public static void invokeFragmentButtonHandler(View v, int callsAbove) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
        String methodName = getCallingMethodName(callsAbove+1);
        Fragment f = OnClickFragments.getTagFragment(v);
        Method m = f.getClass().getMethod(methodName, new Class[] { View.class });
        m.invoke(f, v);
    }
    public static void invokeFragmentButtonHandler(View v) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
        invokeFragmentButtonHandler(v,1);
    }
    public static void invokeFragmentButtonHandlerNoExc(View v) {
        try {
            invokeFragmentButtonHandler(v,1);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void registerTagFragment(View rootView, Fragment fragment) {
        rootView.setTag(new FragmentHolder(fragment));
    }
}
```

And the next adventure will be proguard obfuscation...

PS

It is of course up to you to design your application so that the data live in the *Model* rather than in Activities or Fragments (which are *Controllers* from the *MVC*, *Model-View-Controller* point of view). The *View* is what you define via xml, plus the custom view classes (if you define them, most people just reuse what already is). A rule of thumb: if some data definitely must survive the screen turn, they belong to *Model*.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.writeqrcode_main, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    txt_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    txt_usranme = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.surname);
    txt_number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);
    txt_province = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.province);
    txt_write = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_write);
    txt_show1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonShow1);

    txt_show1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Onclick","Onclick");

            txt_show1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            txt_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txt_usranme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txt_number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txt_province.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

You OK !!!!

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the question?  What do you mean by your sentence at the end?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use data binding you can follow this solution
The following solution might be a better one to follow. the layout is in fragment_my.xml

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="listener"
        type="my_package.MyListener" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/moreTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{() -> listener.onClick()}"
        android:text="@string/login"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the Fragment would be as follows

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(), MyListener {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
            return FragmentMyBinding.inflate(
                inflater,
                container,
                false
            ).apply {
                lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
                listener = this@MyFragment
            }.root
    }

    override fun onClick() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}

interface MyListener{
    fun onClick()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's too late, but I have a more convenient solution. First, create a method in the `MainActivity` class called `insertIntoDb(view: View)`. Second, make sure you have a reference to the fragment in the `MainActivity` class. If you're using the Navigation component, you can use the `NavHostFragment` to retrieve the currently displayed fragment. After that, check if the current fragment is of the desired fragment type. If it is, cast it to the appropriate fragment class. Then, call the desired method on the fragment instance.

```
fun insertIntoDb(view: View) {
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main) as NavHostFragment
    val currentFragment = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment
    if (currentFragment is YourFragment) {
        val yourFragment = currentFragment as YourFragment
        // Now you have access to the public methods defined in YourFragment class
        yourFragment.insertIntoDb(view)
    }
}
```