# how to implement Buttons clickhandler on Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-button

I'm still confused how to implement button handler on Fragments.

Here is my Fragment:

```
package com.example.myshops_diary;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Item1_fragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener { 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item1_fragment, container, false);

    Button nextpageButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nextpageButton);
nextpageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.nextpageButton:
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        break;
    }

}

private void setContentView(int item2_Fragment) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    //---Inflate the layout for this fragment---
//return inflater.inflate( R.layout.item1_fragment, container, false);



}





}
```

These codes are still not working at all, when I clicked the Next button the app stopped running.

** these are my LogCat :

```
04-14 13:00:15.899: D/dalvikvm(537): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-14 13:00:17.359: D/gralloc_goldfish(537): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-14 13:00:28.289: D/AndroidRuntime(537): Shutting down VM
04-14 13:00:28.299: W/dalvikvm(537): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method nextClick(View) in the activity class com.example.myshops.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'nextpageButton'
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3026)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: nextClick [class android.view.View]
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3019)
04-14 13:00:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: What do you want to do: add another fragment inside your layout?

Comment: no , just to make the button works ... there are few button inside the fragment

Comment: Ok, post the logcat. I'll try to help you.

Comment: ok the logcat have been posted , please help me out @Fllo

Answer (score 0):

Your `onClick` method looks good. I don't know what you tried to do, however you **cannot** set a content view twice. You already inflated a view inside `onCreateView` method:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.item1_fragment, container, false);
```

Then you cannot call this code below to add a layout. This is the cause of your crash:

```
setContentView(R.layout.item2_fragment);
```

Also make sure that the button clicked inside your layout has this id:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextpageButton"
    ... />
```

Because of the `android:onClick="nextClick"` attribute, you have this error: `NoSuchMethodException: nextClick`. It means that **the system cannot find a method called nextClick**. You try to call `onClickListener` method **and** an `onClick` method provide by the button.

Then, remove the attribute in your layout and keep this part inside your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        // This will display a Toast (msg) when the button is clicked
        case R.id.nextpageButton:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

[See the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents) to see the two different methods.

**Update**

You set the click listener as follows:

```
// Here the inflated view (the layout) and the button are the same variable..
view = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nextpageButton);
view.setOnClickListener(this);
```

But you should use a different variable to your button as follows:

```
// Here we give another name variable as "button_name" and also we set the widget "Button"
Button button_name = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nextpageButton);
button_name.setOnClickListener(getActivity());
```

---

**Solution**

Here another method, call directly the onClickListener without the implement. Remove this:

```
implements OnClickListener // on your Fragment Class declaration
```

Then:

```
nextpageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

---

**Solution2**

Remove all the onClick method, etc. in your Activity. Add the following attribute inside the layout:

```
android:onClick="nextpageButton" // on your button
```

Then **inside your activity**:

```
// call the "nextpageButton" inside your activity as
public void nextpageButton(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: ok trying it now ... actually i have concerned about the button functionality itself , it suppose to direct the page to the next page 
but seems like from your updated code , it doesnt show any functions to make it move to (navigate) the next page at all 
@Fllo

Comment: its not working .. i think it should have changed to direct the current page to the next page (other fragments) .. @Fllo

Comment: @user3514625 the solution2 is inside your Activity, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21192511/2668136) and this will work for sure!

Comment: ... Well... I don't really know now. I tried everything to understand. I can just say one last thing: sorry and good luck ;) I really hope you will find the right way.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements
        OnClickListener {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_job_seeker_home,
                container, false);
        Button bu = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.next);
        bu.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.next:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your xml layout?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your MainActivity, first inflate the fragment,

```
MainFragment framgmentInstance=new MainFragment();
this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,framgmentInstance,"tag").commit();
```

Button in the fragment layout should looks like this,

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click"
    android:id="@+id/btnOne"
/>
```

As I understand you want to open another activity using the button click event. Correct me if I'm wrong. However, if you want to open a new activity using a button in fragment, try the following code.

```
Button btnOne=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
    btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),secondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

'secondActivity' is the name of the activity that you want to open.