# get the fragment that includes a particular view

Tags: android, android-fragments

**How do I find the fragment that includes a particular view?**

It is easy to find a view knowing the fragment and the view id:

```
fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.foo)
```

But what I want to do is the reversal: knowing the view, find the fragment.

Comment: loop in your fragments list and check if "fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.foo) != null "

Answer (score 0):

So far the best idea is:

I. Set the root view's tag to the fragment that inflated it:

```
// in a class that extends Fragment:
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_id, container, false);

    rootView.setTag(this); // <======= !!!

    return rootView;
}
```

II. Then, it's relatively easy to find that root view among view's parents:

```
// in some utility class:
public static Fragment getTagFragment(View view) {
    for (View v = view; v != null; v = (v.getParent() instanceof View) ? (View)v.getParent() : null) {
        Object tag = v.getTag();
        if (tag != null && tag instanceof Fragment) {
            return (Fragment)tag;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

III. Usage:

```
    Fragment f = getTagFragment(view);
```

PS I can even [place an onClick handler into a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26887675/755804), and it works!