# Setting onClick event for Custom Action Bar items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, onclicklistener

I am getting following exception when I am trying to add onClick event on the item of Custom ActionBar.My app crashes when I click on  `searchiconactionbar` in ActionBar.I have put method onClick() in activity only.Why am I getting this error?Is there any other way for setting the onClickListener for Custom ActionBar items?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method clickEvent(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageView with id 'searchiconactionbar'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4466)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18542)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: clickEvent [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3831)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java
```

actionbar_gip

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/tabbackground"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/actionsearchtext"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
android:visibility="gone"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"

        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Search for all GIFs"
        android:textColorHint="#544E4B"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/usericonlayout"
        android:background="@color/border_gray"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/usericonlayout"

        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/searchiconactionbar"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:onClick="clickEvent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code-

```
        LayoutInflater mInflater2 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View mCustomView2 = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_gip, null);
  searchtext=(EditText)mCustomView2.findViewById(R.id.actionsearchtext);
        searchIcon=(ImageView)mCustomView2.findViewById(R.id.searchiconactionbar);
          getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_gip);
   public void clickEvent(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.searchiconactionbar) {
            if (searchtext.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                expand(searchtext);
            else
                collapse(searchtext);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: And the error is ... ?

Comment: @Samurai forgot to post the error..now posted in question.check

Comment: @Sunil log error posted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28518050/1235910

Comment: @Palejandro so whts the problem in my code?

Comment: @BhuvneshVarma you're getting the error when you click on  your searchiconactionbar in ActionBar?

Comment: Can you try this instead (right before `setCustomView` : `searchIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click Worked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });`

Comment: And remove the `onClick` from xml.

Comment: @Samurai i tried..it never goes inside `searchIcon.setOnClickListener`..no toast message displayed..

Comment: Mmm ... any change if you use `getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(mCustomView2);` istead?

Comment: @Samurai I have added almost complete activity code..please check it out..

Comment: @Samurai  I tried changing actionbar_title programically and its NOT working.I have posted almost complete activity code..please let me know where my action bar implementation is wrong..check the updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76928/discussion-between-samurai-and-bhuvnesh-varma).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing

```
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_gip);
```

by

```
 getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(mCustomView2);
```

solved my issue..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which has onClick() functionality for custom views in action bar.

layout for custom action bar :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_back_iv"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/small_margin_ar"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/very_small_margin_ar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/up_navigation"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_titleText_tv"
    style="@style/wrapscreen"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/custom_actionbar_back_iv"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/above_medium_text_size" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_goToArchiveActivity_ib"
    style="@style/wrapscreen"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/medium_margin"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" />
```

Here goes the implementation..

Define setupactionBar() method in onCreate() method

```
private void setUpActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View customActionBarView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

        // this view is used to show tile
        TextView ActivityTitleTV = (TextView) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_titleText_tv);
        ActivityTitleTV.setText(R.string.title_text_archive);

        //this view can be used for back navigation
        ImageView backToRecorderIV = (ImageView) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_back_iv);
        backToRecorderIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        backToRecorderIV.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Another view which has up navigation
        ImageButton goToArchiveActivityIB = (ImageButton) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_goToArchiveActivity_ib);
        goToArchiveActivityIB.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }

    //listener for back navigation
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.custom_actionbar_back_iv:
                Intent recorder = new Intent(ArchiveActivity.this, RecorderActivity.class);
                startActivity(recorder);
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps...