# Add a search button to maps

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to add a search bar to android maps. 
The map is added as one of the fragment to the project. The error seems be introduced by `this`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Maps extends Fragment {
    //Initial code

   public void onSearch(View view) {
        EditText location_tf = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.TFaddress);
        String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
        List < Address > addressList = null;

        if (location != null || !location.equals(""))
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Address address = addressList.get(0);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}
```

xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText android:layout_width="287dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/TFaddress"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="onSearch" />
        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Error:

```
Error:(83, 46) error: incompatible types: MAPS cannot be converted to Context
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output.    
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'. Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), the `Geocoder` constructor expects a `Context`, not a `Fragment`, so this line

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
```

should be

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
```

Also, take into account that you may want to add brackets in your `if` statement:

```
if (location != null || !location.equals(""))
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

    try {
        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, after rectifying my code, when I try to run it,  the TomCat:                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onSearch(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'

Comment: Try making your `onSearch(View view)` public: `public onSearch(View view)`

Comment: My mistake, your `onSearch` method must be on your `Activity`, not your `Fragment` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192386/android-fragment-onclick-button-method