# Android call a method on fragment with onClick error

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-fragments

i am populating a set of `custom_rows` into my `listview` from `baseadapter`.
And i set the listview in my fragment.
I am trying to set `android:onClick="openComment` to the button which is in my `custom_row.xml` but the i get the below error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method openComment(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'open'
```

In my Fragment i have the method openComment. How do i call the the method from the button click.
This is Fragment shows how i call the method.

```
public class Home extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
....
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container,false);
    listView = (ListView) myview.findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
return myview;
}
....
....
public void openComment(View v)
{
  //getting the position of clicked row
  final int position = listView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
  System.out,print("button clicked");
}
```

my `custom_row.xml` looks like this. it has a textview and a button

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/open"
            android:onClick="openComment"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is my ListView  `activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/custom_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>
```

Comment: where is the onClick method, and where you call it ?!!

Comment: check my xml. i call it from xml button

Comment: @Naz141, have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192386/android-fragment-onclick-button-method), see if it helps given that you are using Fragment

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you must declare your `openComment(View v)` function inside your host `activity` instead of your `fragment`. You can declare the function inside your `activity` as below:

```
public void openComment(View v){
    yourFragment.openComment(v);
}
```

However, I dont think it's a good idea to solve this way. You should implement `onClickListener` inside your adapter or your fragment.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this and even though it’s been over a year since @Kingfisher Phuoc gave the correct answer, I’d like to share my view as well.

> However, I dont think it's a good idea to solve this way.

I couldn’t agree more. It isn’t the best practice to write the logic of a button that’s inside a fragment inside the activity containing the fragment rather than the fragment itself. It’s against the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and it’s a shame that Google designed Android in a way that it prevents developers to make use of best practices.

So how I do it:

Check out JakeWharton’s [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife) library. With this you can bind the views.

So in your activity class’ onCreate you do:

```
// Bind your views here using @BindView(R.id.someview) MyView myView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

and bind the views it contains. Just like that inside the fragment class’ onCreateView you do:

```
// Bind your views here using @BindView(R.id.someview) MyView myView;
@BindView(R.id.custom_list)
ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    // Make sure you unbind too as fragments work differently than activities, check the documentation on how.
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}
```

Check out the [documentation](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) and you can even find code to simplify your BaseAdapter implementation to connect openComment to OnClick properly rather than defining it in XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
private ListView listView;
private View myview;

...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container,false);
    listView = (ListView) myview.findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Use the position argument
            if(view.getId() == R.id.open)
                System.out.print("button clicked");
        }
    });

    return myview;
}
```

And you won't need that `:onClick` attribute in your XML layout.

Comment: Thanks, I know this. i have to call a method on click on button only. not the listview. because i have three buttons. and each button has to call different methods.

Answer (score 0):

call it from BaseAdapter. like

```
 Button btn_opencomment=(Button)yourview.findViewById(R.id.open); 

      btn_opencomment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @override
    public void onClick(View v)
   {
  //getting the position of clicked row
      final int position = listView.getPositionForView((View)              
      v.getParent());
      System.out,print("button clicked");
   //this is your method.what ever you have to do onclick of item.write here..
    });
    return yourview;
     }
```

Comment: remove onclick in xml layout.

Comment: i have tried this. its gives the error.
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: null pointer exception raises because your binding the controls is not proper.check the binding correctly.

Comment: the error occurs because `findViewById(R.id.open)` is not found in the View

Comment: yes,i said you alredy i think.NullPointerException raises if your binding is not proper.Is your issue fixed?

Comment: the issue is not fixed

Comment: can you explain the issue or what you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: i want to call the method when on button click. 
because i use fragment the method is not called. but for Activity it is called

Comment: okay.now write your method somewhere in the fragment and use my above code..write the above in getview of BaseAdpater.and in onClick call your mathod,this will work .

Comment: i tried like you told. i put the onclick listener on my getView in baseadapter.
it gives error NullPointerException

Comment: can you paste the exception here as it is

Comment: i get `NullPointerException` at the line  `btn_opencomment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`

Comment: i think im doing it correct. so from getView if i want to call the method from fragment. i have to make the method static. it causes problem