# Android ImageButton onClick, missing something important?

Tags: android, url, imagebutton

I tried opening a url following some others questions, but the onClick event just restart the app and its not opening the browser. Thx for the help

**UPDATE:** This works for activities not for fragments.

this is my .xml button

```
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="EnterButton"/>
```

This is my .java with the implemented method.

```
public void EnterButton(View view) {
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if your "EnterButton" is triggered? You can also check if your device can handle this intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries, this is working for my fragments. The other methods from the interface are not modified.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        ImageButton b = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

     public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageButton2:
                 String url = "http://www.google.com";
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                 startActivity(intent);
              break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

just use this

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
```

**full code :**

```
public void EnterButton(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use This code its work Man...

```
public void EnterButton(View view) {
String url = "http://www.google.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is intended to work on activity not on Fragments ,reference :https://stackoverflow.com/a/21192511/3111083

But you can do this on fragment instead.

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v)
             {
                // do something
             } 
   });
```