# Implement a button in a fragment for tabbed activity after click should goto new activity

Tags: android

This is the code for the fragment. Please help me place a button and `onClick` it should go to the respective activity

```
class boards extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.boards, container, false);

}

}
```

Comment: There are hundreds of examples already available. What problems are you having in implementing any of them?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192386/android-fragment-onclick-button-method

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onViewCreated` method:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.boards, container, false);
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // do something
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class));
    } 
}); 
return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement a call back interface

interface code :

```
public interface FragmentCallback {
   void changeActivity();
}
```

inside fragment:

```
FragmentCallback mListener;

void setListener(FragmentCallback listener){
    mListener=listener;
}
```

inside activity:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentCallback{

Boards fragment=new Boards();  //class name shoud be capital i.e Boards

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        fragment.setListener(this);
    }

@Override
void changeActivity(){
   Intent intent =new Intent(this,newActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

use the below code to change activity from fragment :

```
if(mListener!=null)
   mListener.changeActivity()
```

below code will do the task