# when I click on the button the app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Here the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method OpenRadio(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'RadioPootis'
```

java code:

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link Fragment1#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Fragment1.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Fragment1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }

    String url = "https://epicmario71.tk";

    public void OpenRadio(View view) {
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getActivity(), Uri.parse(url));
    }
}
```

xml file:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/background"
    tools:context=".ui.main.Fragment1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/webp_net_resizeimage__6_"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/webp_net_resizeimage__6_"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/RadioPootis"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/webp_net_resizeimage__6_"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/RadioPootis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="OpenRadio"
        android:src="@drawable/webp_net_resizeimage__6_"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

when I click on the button the app crashes

Using tabbed activity from android studio example whit legacy android studio libraries

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `android:onClick` attribute in fragment layout unless you create it in the activity class, not the fragment class.

In your case:

> `Here the error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method OpenRadio(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class`

The system looks at the activity class that hosts `Fragment1`, and didn't find `OpenRadio(View)` method.

So, you need to either move the `OpenRadio(View)` method to the activity class in case the code it holds is not relevant to the fragment; or you need to build some communication between the fragment and the activity when `OpenRadio(View)` of the activity is called, for this part you can check [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192386/android-fragment-onclick-button-method/).