# fragment vs activity onClickButton functions - where is right place

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity

I made an andorid application using the "activity" component. I used it for a while, but over time I found that one page was not enough for me. I needed to add `tabLayout`, `viewPager2` and three `fragments`.
I needed to migrate the functionality from `mainActivity` to the `firstFragment`.

I encountered a problem with events during the XML migration. In the activity I called android: `onClick = "myOnClicFunction"`. But is that not possible?

I know that this has been discussed several times here in several threads. However, I would like to ask how to proceed correctly.

Here in the thread [Android Fragment onClick button Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192386/android-fragment-onclick-button-method) is the advice "even if you are in the fragment, put the onClick functions into activity" there is another similar advice to, "if you insist to make it in a fragment"

But what is right? Should the onclick function be correct in the activity or in the fragment?

I don't want to put the source code here, because I don't know which procedure is correct at all.

I am creating a program that is for testing students. An example is displayed and a response is pending.

The first tab has a lot of buttons + saves the result to an xml files.

The second tab will contain statistics. From saved files displays how many calculations were correct, wrong, average response time, etc ...

In Activity I had functions like `getQuestion(), evaluateQuestion(), saveToXml() and events zeroWasPressed(), oneWasPressed(), twoWasPressed(), threeWasPressed()` ...

Where should I put all these functions when I change the application from Activity to Fragment?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. on click function listener should be placed in corresponding fragment, where the button is added in fragment layout.
2. events zeroWasPressed(), oneWasPressed(), twoWasPressed(), threeWasPressed() ... should be placed inside corresponding fragment where those buttons were added in layout.

   getQuestion(), evaluateQuestion(), saveToXml() , this function can be placed in your activity or some other custom classes, that would appropriate according to architecture viewpoint.