# When Onclick operates in fragment xml, app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new to the development scene and I'm just trying my hand at fragments. I have an onClick event defined in one of my fragment XML files, but when I click the button my app crashes.

I've surmised that this happens because my onClick event is defined in my fragment and not my `MainActivity`, so I was just wondering what is the best practice to get my buttons working. Should I just pass the button along to my fragment, or should I move my onClick event to my `MainActivity` then reference it from my fragment?

***************** this is the code ****************

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1.5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/txt_textInputLayout_three"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_calendar_today_24">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_from_user1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="From"
                    android:onClick="openDataPicker_from"
                    android:inputType="text" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="2">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/txt_textInputLayout_four"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_calendar_today_24">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_to_user1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="To"
                    android:onClick="openDatePicker_to"
                    android:inputType="text" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Java file*****

```
 public void openDatePicker_from(View view) {
        dataPickerDialog_from.show();

    }

    public void openDatePicker_to(View view) {
        dataPickerDialog_to.show();


    }
```

**this the error**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method openDataPicker(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText with id 'txt_from_user1'
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:5368)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked, Try this

```
FromDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dataPickerDialog_from.show();
            }
        });

        ToDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dataPickerDialog_to.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method openDataPicker(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText with id 'txt_from_user1'
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:5368)
```

This error because it can't find the method `openDataPicker(View)` in the activity class (even if you already adding it to the fragment class).

Using `android:onClick` attribute in fragments is not exactly the same as in activities; weather you use it in activity or in fragment, it expects to see the method `openDataPicker()` only in the activity class.

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192386/android-fragment-onclick-button-method) to see how to use `android:onClick` attribute in the fragment, or you can normally use the `myButton.setOnClickListener()` programmatically.

**UPDATE:**

> So can you tell me according to the code, what I want to change in the code clearly

You can use `setOnClickListener()` in the fragment.

```
TextInputEditText editTextFrom = requireView().findViewById(R.id.txt_from_user1);
editTextFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dataPickerDialog_from.show();
    }
});


TextInputEditText editTextTo = requireView().findViewById(R.id.txt_to_user1);
editTextTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dataPickerDialog_to.show();
    }
});
```

And then remove the `onClick` attributes from the XML:

```
android:onClick="openDatePicker_to"


android:onClick="openDataPicker_from"
```

Comment: So can you tell me according to the code, what I want to change in the code clearly..please.

Comment: @EshanAG Please have a look at the UPDATE section of the answer