# Get edittext value from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using fragments,I have an edittext in fragment and I want to get value in main activity.

This is my fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#878787" >

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="dfgdfgdf"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/user_name"/>

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

    <Button 
        android:text="Gönder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="getFromUser"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am loading fragment with this function:

```
public void startChat(JsonObject user) {
    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("name", user.get("name").getAsString());
    sendTo=user.get("username").getAsString();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ConversationFragment conv = new ConversationFragment();
    conv.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, conv);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}
```

And this is my fragment class

```
public class ConversationFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String name = getArguments().getString("name");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversation, container, false);
        TextView username=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        username.setText(name);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

As you can see when press the button main activity runs "getFromUser" function.I want to get edittext value in this function.How can I do this ?

Comment: "main activity runs "getFromUser" function" doesn't make any sense if you say that's your fragment layout. You mean getFromUser is called inside the fragment?

Comment: @Vlad yes,I mean when user press the button,getFromUser function runs,and this function declared in mainactivity.

Comment: And that is exactly what doesn't work I suppose. The method is never called on button click ...

Comment: can you post your `mainactivity`

Comment: Here full mainactivity:http://pastebin.com/WQHgeCdZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always the same procedure for these things. You can't access a fragment's views just like that. You need a callback method.

Add this code to **ConversationFragment**:

```
private OnGetFromUserClickListener mListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnGetFromUserClickListener ) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnGetFromUserClickListener");
    }
}

public void getFromUser(View v) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
        mListener.getFromUser(edit.getText().toString());
    }
}

public interface OnGetFromUserClickListener {
    void getFromUser(String message);
}
```

Make your MainActivity implement this interface. Replace getFromUser() **inside MainActivity** with:

```
public void getFromUser(String message) {
    sendMessage(message);
}
```

Done.

Edit:
Actually, using the XML-onClick attribute is currently bugged (see [onClick inside fragment called on Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7808223/2964379)): It links to the activity instead of the fragment. You have to set the click listener programmatically to make sure the code won't break at some point in the future. So give the button an ID inside the XML (e.g. get_from_user) and add this code to **onCreateView inside ConversationFragment**:

```
v.findViewById(R.id.get_from_user).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.get_from_user) {
            getFromUser(v);
        }
    }
});
```

Using this code vastly decouples the activity and the fragment from each other.

Comment: As I said, make your activity implement OnGetFromUserClickListener.

Comment: I don't understand how can I implete this code in main activity.Can you look at this ? http://pastebin.com/WQHgeCdZ

Comment: Just do everything above one by one? Don't forget to add ", ConversationFragment.OnGetFromUserClickListener" behind "implements ActionBar.TabListener".

Comment: I did like this: main activity:http://pastebin.com/BuZeK5je this is fragment:http://pastebin.com/0jaMrPw1 but I app is crashing this is the error log:http://prntscr.com/49syle

Comment: I saw your comment but I don't know how can I implement the listener.Can you give an example ?

Comment: public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, ConversationFragment.OnGetFromUserClickListener { ... }

Comment: Thank you so much,it's working now.I have one more question,how can I run a fragment function from main activity ?

Comment: Edit:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659747/call-an-activity-method-from-a-fragment I did like this.What do you think about ? Is valid ?

Comment: Doing it like you already are (using setArguments and getArguments) is best practice. In those cases where you really have to update a fragment when it's already shown, you could call getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(...) or save your fragment in a variable. There's enough information about this here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem.

```
public void getFromUser(View view) {        
    ConversationFragment fragment1 = (ConversationFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    View frag=fragment1.getView();
    EditText editText1 =(EditText) frag.findViewById(R.id.message);
    String message=editText1.getText().toString();
    sendMessage(message);
}
```

Now I can get edittext value from fragment.

Comment: -1. According to [onClick inside fragment called on Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7808223/2964379) onClick is not meant to work this way. It's bad practice and thus not a solution to your issue. My code actually doesn't work because of the bug, which makes sure the fragment's getFromUser is never called. Using mine after I fix it will make sure your code still works in the future.

Comment: But it's working,you mean this code will not work in the future ?

Comment: Not sure, but it might happen. In any case, the code you provided works, but it's not clean code (see [this answer and its comments to How to handle button clicks using the xml onClick within Fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6271637/2964379)). This actually seems to be a quite delicate topic.

Comment: What harm would possibly occur you think, if i use the code I've given above? you made me suspect

Comment: Most importantly you lose the advantage of fragments being interchangeable (see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html for more on that). Beside that Google might decide to fix this "bug" and onClick will link to the underlying fragment instead of its container activity. In that case you'll have to switch to my solution without the edit anyway.

Comment: @Tolgay... hi can you tell me wt is container in R.id.container  represent...i saw ur question but i didnt get it, is it the baseActivity from which the fragement has created??