# onClick method works only in MainActivity

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-imagebutton

I have a ImageButton and i want to use it in a certain Fragment class of my application. But when i use it in my fragment class the app crashes. BUT i can use it in my MainActivity without crashing. How can i fix this?

This is the code i'm using in my fragment class

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity, v);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.song_popup, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();

    }
```

This results in a app crash.But when i use this in my MainActivity (in mainactivity "activity" is replaced by this.getApplicationContext) it works.

My button xml

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/popUp"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha"
                android:onClick="showPopup" />
```

**LOGCAT**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method showPopup(View) in the activity class com.fm.etunes.phone.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'popUp'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3814)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: showPopup [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3807)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21192511/1479511

Comment: check answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7808223/1168654 solution is http://stackoverflow.com/a/6271637/1168654

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method
>   showPopup(View) in the activity class com.fm.etunes.phone.MainActivity
>   for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id
>   'popUp'

You are getting this exception because this click method is supposed be defined in your activity, not in fragment.

More in detail, `android:onClick` only works for the activity. So if you would want to define it for the fragment layout then you have to define the click listener in the parent activity, from where you call the fragment.

In your case, just move the `showPopup(View v)` method in the parent activity, from where you are replacing the fragment.

Comment: can you explain more with some code?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD can you read the answer fully and try implementing yourself first?