# Application modularity when using Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, modularity

I would like to use tabs in my Android application and since `TabActivity` is deprecated, I want to do it the `Fragment` way.

I already constructed the skeleton of the app, and I have 3 tabs, and each the tab has its own seperate `Fragment`.

**My questions are:**

1. I ended up having 1 Activity for the whole app and a lot of fragments. Is this normal?
2. In the fragments I have buttons. Each `onClick` method of these buttons expect to has its handler in the Activity. I've found this post: [Handling onClick events with fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments). Seriously?? The `Activity` will catch all the onclick's events from all the fragments and call the appropriate method of the relevant fragment?? Can't I handle the `onclick` event of a button that located inside a fragment in the fragment's code?? If I can't, Google should get some spanks!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to question number 2 is to implement `onClick` in the code of the `Fragment`... No way of doing this in the XML?