# Using android:onlick within ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've implemented a ViewPager with 3 fragments and a lot of checkboxes within each fragment. In the xml-layouts I'm using

> android:onclick="onCheckboxClicked"

In each fragment I've implemented a method for checking the states of the checkboxes:

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.cb_one:
            if (checked) 
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "cb_one checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "cb_one unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.cb_two:
            // ... 
    }
}
```

Well, this doesn't really work, because the application crashes each time I select a checkbox.

> E/AndroidRuntime(29283): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onCheckboxClicked(View) in the activity class **com.testApp.SomeFragmentActivity** for onClick handler on view class android.widget.CheckBox with id 'cb_one'

I couldn't find a proper solution to get this running.

Any suggestions? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't supported. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments) for some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You said you put it in the fragment, but the exception text you provided says it's looking for it in an *activity* called com.testApp.SomeFragmentActivity.

Comment: Yes, so the only solution is the implement the method inside the activity? :(

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use **setOnCheckedChangeListener**  instead of **onClickListener** to handle checkboxes

*here is the sample code*

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
            CheckBox checkboxFirst = rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_first);
            checkboxFirst.setOnCheckedChangeListener(ViewpagerFragmentFirst.this);
        
    }



    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        case R.id.checkbox_first: {
            if (isChecked) {
                // Do something
                Log.i(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: Checked");
            } else {
                // Do something
                Log.i(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: Unchecked");
            }
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```