# How do I get buttons to work?

Tags: android, button, fragment

This code works to the extent I get a list of events.  Select one and go to detail, and I can update etc. and I return to my list.  The first item becomes the "ADD" button and 2ed item becomes the "Exit" function.  But I want real buttons.

I added real buttons and after tries, the code intended to handle the real buttons either has errors or just crashes.  My latest is copied directly from this site:

[How to handle button clicks using the XML onClick within Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments/7969020#7969020)

Look at the code between the double "****".  What am I going wrong?

I included the xml below; I suspect the problem is there.

EventListFragment.java

> ```
> public class EventListFragment extends ListFragment
>                                   implements OnClickListener,
>                                   LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
>    {
>     private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
>     List strRecId = new ArrayList();
>
>     private ListAdapter lstAdapter;
>     private Button btn_Add;
>
>     List strRecord = new ArrayList(3);
>     List strFields = new ArrayList();
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>        {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>          // View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list);
>
> //-----------------------------------------------------;
> // ALSO LOOK FOR "INITRUN" BELOW AND COMMENT OUT STATEMENT;
> //   IN TWO PLACES;
> //-------------------------------------------------------; 
> //  BELOW READS FROM DATABASE AND DISPLAYS EVENTNAME;
> //  THEN ALLOWS UPDATE OF THEM ABD INSERT FROM EXISTING;        
> //      Log.d("EventLst","X onCrt: x01 START" ); 
>
>         String[]  strItems =  new String[]  
>            { 
>             EventProvider.COLUMN_EVENTNAME
>            };
>         Log.d("EventLst","X onCrt: x01strI:" + strItems[0]);          
>         int[] iCnt = new int[]
>            {  
>             R.id.text1
>          };
>         mAdapter =  new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.event_row,
>                     null, strItems, iCnt,  0);
>         Log.d("EventLst","X onCrt: x02 START" );
>
>         setListAdapter(mAdapter);
>   getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
>
>   Log.d("EventLst","X onCrt: x03 START" );
>
>        }  //----> backto public void onCreate
>
> //
> //-------------------------------------------------------
> //      Log.d("EventLst","X onCrt: DONE" ); 
> //---------------------------------------------------------     
>
>
>     @Override
>     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
> //*      The activity (not fragment's) onCreate() method returns and calls
> //*       onActivityCreated() callback
>        { 
>   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
>   Log.d("EventLst","S onActCrtd");
> //* The ListFragment supports showing a message when the list is empty.  Uses a
> //* value of R.string.loadingmsg - Add to strings.xml
>   setEmptyText(getResources().getString(R.string.loadingmsg));    
>   registerForContextMenu(getListView());
>   setHasOptionsMenu(true);
>
>   Log.d("EventLst","X onActCrtd" );
>        } 
>
>     //*---------------------------------------------------------------
>     //*      START EDIT ACTIVITY:    
>             //  user clicked in list, start edit view
>             // startActivity (...) starts edit activity, passing id = n
>             //      where "n" is (record key) id from list
>         @Override
>         public void onListItemClick(ListView l,View V, int position, long id)
>            {
>             super.onListItemClick(l, V, position,  id);
>             Log.d("EventLst","S onLsItmCk" + ";P:" + position + ";I:" + id);
>             long lgRecN = 0;
>     // id is the position in the list of activities,
>     //     we will use it to get the RowId of this record in DB  
>         if (id == 1)
>            {
>            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
>            }
>         if (id > 0)
>            {
>             String strRecN = (String) strRecId.get((int) id-1);    
>             lgRecN = Long.parseLong(strRecN); 
>            }
>         else
>            {
>             lgRecN = 0;
>            };
>         startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), EventEditActivity.class)
>               .putExtra(EventProvider.COLUMN_ROWID, lgRecN) );
>         // Log.d("EventLst","X onLsItmCk" + ";I:" + id);       
>        }
> //****************************************************;        
> //****************************************************;    
> //  This was copied precisely from:
>
> //      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-
> //          the-xml-onclick-within-fragments/7969020#7969020
> //     then shangrd "StartButton" to  btn_Exit
> // I had errors     
>
>     //@Override
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                Bundle savedInstanceState)
>        {
>         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list, container, false);
>         Log.d("EventLst","S creatrView");
>         Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_Add);
>         b.setOnClickListener(this);
>         Log.d("EventLst","S onLsItmCk" + v);
>         return v;
>        }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v)
>            {
>             Log.d("EventLst","S onclkBtn" + v);
>            }  
> //**************************************************;    
> //***************************************************;    
>     @Override
>     public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
>        {
>         super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
>         Log.d("EventLst","S onVwCrt");
>       setEmptyText(getResources().getString(R.string.loadingmsg));
>         registerForContextMenu(getListView());
>       Log.d("EventLst","X onVwCrt");
>        }
> ```

event_list.xml

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> android:name="com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListFragment" >
>  <Button  android:id="@+id/btn_Add"
>     android:layout_width="50dp"
>     android:layout_height="30dp"   
>     android:textSize="12dp"
>     android:padding="1dip"
>     android:text="@string/add" />
>   <Button  android:id="@+id/btn_Exit"
>     android:layout_width="50dp"
>     android:layout_height="30dp"
>     android:textSize="12dp"
>     android:padding="1dip"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Add" 
>     android:text="@string/exit" />
>   <Button  android:id="@+id/btn_Other"
>     android:layout_width="50dp"
>     android:layout_height="30dp"
>     android:textSize="12dp"
>     android:padding="1dip"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Exit" 
>     android:text="@string/other" />
>  <fragment
>     android:name="com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListFragment"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Add"  />
>  </RelativeLayout>
> ```

event_row.xml

> ```
>   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/text1"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>     android:textSize="12dp"
>     android:padding="2dip" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get what you really want but i assume that you have a problem with the button click ? if i am right. you can use one of these ways.

1- in your layout add this simple code to your button

```
android:onClick="MyButton"
```

and in you class add

```
public void MyButton(View v) {
// you may want to perform your clicks here.
}
```

2- you can use directly from your class

```
MyButtonId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        // you may want to perform your clicks here.

        }
    });
```

Comment: First, Thanks for the reply.  Also thanks to @alex for making it readable.
My follow-up didn't get posted, so I will re-ask:

XML = <Button android:id="@+id/btn_Add" android:onClick="myButton" . . .

JAVA = myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) { Log.d(. . . ); } } );

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com. .../com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListActivity}: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496

Comment: However: With same XML: (android:onClick="myButton" . . .)

Tried this, NOT in onCreate,
 
public void myButton(View v)
{  Log.d(" . . .");   }

I get:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method myButton(View) in the activity

So aI am still doing something wrong!  Probably very basic.

My screen is a fragment with dynamic list and now 3 buttons.
I just want to select a button and invoke code - for now a "log.d...;" will make me happy!

Comment: I have about come to the conclusion that my problem is that while clicking items in my list created by "setListAdapter(lstAdapter);"  can be handled by the fragment, a button cannot.  Why the two are different, I do not understand. 

Unless there is a better way, I guess I spend the next couple days moving the fragment code into the activity.  However, can someone tell me if I can use setListAdapter the same way on the activity?