# Button ClickHandler not working with Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, fragment

I have a button that is in a layout which is set to On Click = calculateClickHandler
When clicking the button the app closes with the following logcat. I'm not sure if this is because i'm trying to do this in the Fragment and should be doing it in the main activity?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method calculateClickHandler(View) in the activity class com.HealthKicks.bodystats.admob.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'calculatewaist'
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3620)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: calculateClickHandler [class android.view.View]
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3613)
10-23 15:59:30.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22388):    ... 11 more
```

Here is the Fragment code:

```
package com.HealthKicks.bodystats.admob;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DummySectionFragment1 extends Fragment {

    Button calculatewaist;
    EditText waist_edit_text1;
    RadioGroup gender_radio_group1;
    RadioButton gender_radio_male, gender_radio_female;
    Spinner waist_spinner;
    TextView ideal, high, veryhigh;
    String waist_unit, waist;

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.waist, container, false);

         // get the references to the widgets
        waist_spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.waist_spinner);
        waist_edit_text1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.waist_edit_text1);
        ideal = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ideal);
        high = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.high);
        veryhigh = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.veryhigh);
        gender_radio_male = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gender_radio_male);
        gender_radio_female = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gender_radio_female);
        calculatewaist = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calculatewaist);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        calculateClickHandler(view);
    }



    void calculateClickHandler(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (view.getId() == R.id.calculatewaist) {

        // Get the users values from the widget references
            waist_unit = waist_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            float waist = Float.parseFloat(waist_edit_text1.getText().toString());

        // Convert Inches to CM
            if (waist_unit.equals("INCHES")) {
                waist = (float) (waist * 2.54);
                }

        // Interpret what Waist Circumference result means for male

                    if (waist < 94 && (gender_radio_male.isChecked())){
                   ideal.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.title_color));
                     } else if (waist < 103 && (gender_radio_male.isChecked())) {

                   high.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.title_color));
                     } else if (waist > 102 && (gender_radio_male.isChecked())) {

                   veryhigh.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.title_color));

                     }

             // Interpret what Waist Circumference result means for female

                    if (waist < 80 && (gender_radio_female.isChecked())) {
                   ideal.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.title_color));
                     } else if (waist < 89 && (gender_radio_female.isChecked())) {

                   high.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.title_color));
                     } else if (waist > 88 && (gender_radio_female.isChecked())) {

                   veryhigh.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.title_color));

                     }
        };
    }
}
```

and the main activity code:

```
package com.HealthKicks.bodystats.admob;

import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    EditText waist_edit_text1;
    RadioGroup gender_radio_group1;
    RadioButton gender_radio_male, gender_radio_female;
    Spinner waist_spinner;
    TextView ideal, high, veryhigh;
    String waist_unit, waist;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    private final String TAG = "Main Activity";

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.Refresh:
            Log.i(TAG, "Refresh Item Clicked");
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.Info:
            Log.i(TAG, "Info Item Clicked");
            return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;

              case 1:
                Fragment fragment1 = new DummySectionFragment1();
                Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
                args1.putInt(DummySectionFragment1.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 2);
                fragment1.setArguments(args1);
                return fragment1;

              case 2:

                 Fragment fragment2 = new DummySectionFragment2();
                 Bundle args2 = new Bundle();
                 args2.putInt(DummySectionFragment2.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 3);
                 fragment2.setArguments(args2);
                 return fragment2;

              case 3:

                     Fragment fragment3 = new DummySectionFragment3();
                     Bundle args3 = new Bundle();
                     args3.putInt(DummySectionFragment3.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 4);
                     fragment3.setArguments(args3);
                     return fragment3;

            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error too, and it is NOT because I don't have the right method in the right activity. Something else is going on here, but not sure what.

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method calculateClickHandler(View) in the activity class com.HealthKicks.bodystats.admob.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'calculatewaist'"`

That really tells you all you need to know about how to solve this:
**Place the method in the Activity instead**

Another alternative is to use the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments/14571018#14571018), where you in the `Fragment` implement `OnClickListener` and use this code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false);
    Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.StartButton);
    b.setOnClickListener(this); // This is the important line here!
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.StartButton:
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```