# Why when I convert Activity to fragment Button not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick

class GamePlay was work well untill I convert Activity to Fragment.

The button not working in layout fragment_game.xml `android:onClick="newGame"` not perform action on click.

I dont want to add Listner.

Many Thanks for any help:-)

```
public void newGame(View view) {
        noughtsTurn = false;
        board = new char[3][3];
        resetButtons();
    }
```

class GamePlay:

```
public class GamePlay extends Fragment {

    // Representing the game state:
    private boolean noughtsTurn = false; // Who's turn is it? false=X true=O
    private char board[][]      = new char[3][3]; // for now we will represent the board as an array of characters

    private LinearLayout          lLayout     = null;
    private FragmentActivity      faActivity  = null;
    /**
    * Called when the activity is first created.
    */

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        faActivity  = (FragmentActivity)    super.getActivity();    
        lLayout    = (LinearLayout)    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);


            setupOnClickListeners();
            resetButtons();
            return lLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Called when you press new game.
     *
     * @param view the New Game Button
     */
    public void newGame(View view) {
        noughtsTurn = false;
        board = new char[3][3];
        resetButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Reset each button in the grid to be blank and enabled.
     */
    private void resetButtons() {
        TableLayout T = (TableLayout) lLayout.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
        for (int y = 0; y < T.getChildCount(); y++) {
            if (T.getChildAt(y) instanceof TableRow) {
                TableRow R = (TableRow) T.getChildAt(y);
                for (int x = 0; x < R.getChildCount(); x++) {
                    if (R.getChildAt(x) instanceof Button) {
                        Button B = (Button) R.getChildAt(x);
                        B.setText("");
                        B.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

fragment_game.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:id="@+id/titleText" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Game"
            android:id="@+id/newGameBtn" 
            android:layout_column="0" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="newGame"/>
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout">
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="O"
                    android:textSize="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/topLeft" android:layout_column="1" android:width="100dp" android:height="150dp"/>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:textSize="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_column="2" android:width="100dp" android:height="150dp"/>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:textSize="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_column="3" android:width="100dp" android:height="150dp"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:textSize="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_column="1" android:width="100dp" android:height="150dp"/>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:textSize="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_column="2" android:width="100dp" android:height="150dp"/>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:textSize="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_column="3" android:width="100dp" android:height="150dp"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:textSize="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_column="1" android:width="100dp" android:height="150dp"/>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:textSize="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button6" android:layout_column="2" android:width="100dp" android:height="150dp"/>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:textSize="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button7" android:layout_column="3" android:width="100dp" android:height="150dp"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to manually add the listener, then you must move your onClick method `newGame` into the Activity that your fragment is attached to.

Otherwise, you must programmatically set the OnClickListener in `GamePlay` (check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14571018/855147) for a clever way of doing this)