# Change the NavigationView's header title

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have a `NavigationView` nested inside a `DrawerLayout`.

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

.......

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**drawer_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="150dp"
              android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
              android:gravity="bottom"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="16dp"
              android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawerHeaderTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/drawer_header_text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I access the drawer header's title in Java code ?
I tried to:

1. access it directly using its `id` (***drawerHeaderTitle***) but I get a `NullPointerException`
2. access it via the `NavigationView.findViewById`: same error

How can I overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this approach

```
 mNavigationView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7) {

                mNavigationView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener( this );

                TextView textView = (TextView) mNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.drawerHeaderTitle);

                textView.setText("title");
            }
        });
```

Comment: One more thing : What layout changes does the 'OnLayoutChangeListener' detect ?

Comment: read this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161345/android-support-v23-1-0-update-breaks-navigationview-get-find-header

Answer (score 3):

If you compile with **'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'** you can access your header in this way:

```
private NavigationView mNavigation;
private View mHeaderView;

private TextView mDrawerHeaderTitle;

mNavigation = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
mHeaderView = mNavigation.getHeaderView(0);

mDrawerHeaderTitle = (TextView) mHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.drawerHeaderTitle);
```

More info about this: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View mHeaderView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView companyNameTxt = (TextView) mHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.nav_company_name);
    companyNameTxt.setText("Test Company Name, LLC");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="Dashboard"/>
```

app:title="Dashboard" -> You can change your title here..

Answer (score 0):

```
Declaration 
private NavigationView mNavigationView;
private TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 mTextView = (TextView) mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.id_textView);
 mTextView.setText("text user");
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a short explanation?