# Button "MyButton" is never used

Tags: android, android-fragments, button

I'm facing two issues

- I have in Android Studio a Message that my Buttons are never used: buttonSand and buttonLehm

Here is my code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public void buttonLehm(View view) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lehmBodenTextView);
    if(tv.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
    {
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

public void buttonSand(View view) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.sandBodenTextView);
    if(tv.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
    {
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

and if I run my Code and get to this Fragment and want to test my Buttons, I get this Error Message:

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method buttonLehm(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'lehmBodenButton'
>                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:325)
>                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
>                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Here is the XML-file

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#2fb215"
android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
android:tag="BodenFragment"
android:id="@+id/bodenFragment">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/bodenArtenString"
    android:id="@+id/bodenSeiteUeberschrift"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lehmBodenString"
    android:id="@+id/lehmBodenButton"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:onClick="buttonLehm"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lehmBodenTextString"
    android:id="@+id/lehmBodenTextView"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sandBodenString"
    android:id="@+id/sandBodenButton"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:onClick="buttonSand" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sandBodenTextString"
    android:id="@+id/sandBodenTextView"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

I hope I put enough Code up so somebody can help me with my Problem. I do not know if this helps but somewhere I got the ErrorMessage that I have to import android.widget.View instead of android.view.View but I need both of those and I can not reproduce this error at the moment for clarification.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide the code of the fragment and the activity?

Comment: What does your `onCreateView` method look like?

Comment: Is that the full code? You need to place your methods in a class. You can't have functions without a class in java.

Comment: No that was not the full code, i provided minimal information, so that (I thought) the problem would be easier to find. Thanks for all your reply, I found the Problem myself.
I had the functions in the fragment class and I had to put the functions of the fragment buttons in the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

judging that it is only partial code and seeing that you do `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` my guess is that you put those two methods in a `Fragment`. The thing is that `android:onClick` checks for the method in the `Activity`. So what you just have to do is move those two methods from the Fragment to the Activity the Fragment's in. See also [How to handle button clicks using the XML onClick within Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I just found it myself before I had the opportunity to look up if my question was answered.
That was exactly my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code for the buttons is in the Fragment. You need to change it to be in the Activity for the on-click methods to work.

Answer (score -1):

```
static TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lehmBodenTextView);
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View v;
    //add button onclicklistener with:
    buttonLehm(v);
    buttonSand(v);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.