# Could not find method in a javaclass (extends Fragment)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

trying to call method within a class extends Fragment, from a textview within
layout file. In an activity class I would use this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

What would I do to achieve similarity using a class extends Fragment?

Error from logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method mood(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'moodtw'
```

**Class :**

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
private View rootView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
   return (rootView);


}
public void mood() {
    String tempo;
    int a;
    TextView moodouttw = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.moodouttw);
    tempo = moodouttw.getText().toString();
    a = Integer.parseInt(tempo);
    if (a < 5) {
        a = a + 1;
    } else a = 0;
    tempo = Integer.toString(a);
    moodouttw.setText(tempo);
}
}
```

COULDN'T GET ABOVE TO WORK, so I tried using onclicklistner found in a link from an prev. answer. This also with same error posted above. Looks like app is looking for a method with parameter which, to my knowledge, cant be set in a xml layout file.(?). I might try another approach.Below is copy of last approach and snippet from layout xml file. Thanks to all for help given.

```
    package com.example.android.xxxxx;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.anxietyouttw);
        t.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.anxietyouttw:
                // do something
                String tempo;
                int a;
                TextView anxietyouttw = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.anxietyouttw);
                tempo = anxietyouttw.getText().toString();
                a = Integer.parseInt(tempo);
                if (a < 5) {
                    a = a + 1;
                } else a = 0;
                tempo = Integer.toString(a);
                anxietyouttw.setText(tempo);

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

XML LAYOUT FILE

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headertw1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/anxietyleveltw"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/anxietyleveltw"
        android:text="@string/input_of_general_data_1_of_2"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/anxietyleveltw"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/moodtw"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/moodtw"
android:layout_below="@+id/moodtw"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:onClick="anxiety"
android:text="@string/anixiety"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/anxietyouttw"
android:layout_width="24dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/anxietyleveltw"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/anxietyleveltw"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sleepouttw"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sleepouttw"
android:text="@string/_0"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
android:textIsSelectable="false"
android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Asked already multiple times... Also what do you not understand in *Could not find method mood(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute* Fragment is not Context and mood() is not mood(View)

Comment: hi,  please. My previous issue was findviewbyid which i manage to solve after hours of reading. Now I ask for help with a new issue. I know my previous posts are  shitty  and would delete them if I  could. Sorry  if my last post trigger your anger/frustation.

Comment: One error I could spot is your click handling method(mood) must take  a View as parameter(this view represents the button clicked).
Try
public void mood(View v){
//....
}

this applies when you are using android:onClick from xml file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [findViewById in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

please try this

`setOnClickListener` for the `textview` for which you are setting `OnClick` in xml layout.

For eg

```
private View rootView;
private TextView textView;
```

In `onCreateView`

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.<your textview id>);
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mood();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Tried it. Still cant find method mood(). When mood() is moved from MainActivity class to a class with extends Fragment, mood() is reported not found. My thought is howto make mood() "viewable" ? I have no  answer on that. Thanks for Your suggestion.

Comment: Making mood() viewable directly in Fragment class, I doubt is possible. What I have experienced is Android looks for the method  defined via XML onClick in the activity class rather than Fragment class

Please go through this, I hope you may find it useful

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments

another option is what I have suggested in the answer section, implement listerner in the fragment. If you have tried and mood is not reported , then copy the method mood() into the fragment from activity.

Comment: if you could share xml files as well please?

Comment: Added in original posting now.

Comment: thanks Jane, I copied your xml file and I see few issues
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/moodtw"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sleepouttw"
the ids moodtw and sleepouttw are not defined in the xml file. could you please verify that. Also if you could share main activity code and xml please.

Answer (score 0):

Set View as arg in method

```
 public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
       return (rootView);


    }
    public void mood(View view) {
        String tempo;
        int a;
        TextView moodouttw = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.moodouttw);
        tempo = moodouttw.getText().toString();
        a = Integer.parseInt(tempo);
        if (a < 5) {
            a = a + 1;
        } else a = 0;
        tempo = Integer.toString(a);
        moodouttw.setText(tempo);
    }
    }
```