# How do I know which button does this method correspond to?

Tags: java, android

I am very new to Android Studio, and I have been looking at the official tutorial and found out this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

However, I don't see how that `sendMessage()` method is linked to the button we made in the tutorial. Which line mentions that this method corresponds to the button, which has a name `button_send` and a value of `Send`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle button clicks using the XML onClick within Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML add this attribute "android:onClick="${methodName}" in Button element.

OR:

You can create button object and refference to UI.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Refference UI
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendMessage(view);
        }
    });

}

/** Called when the user taps the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

In your `layout` file `android:onClick="sendMessage"` attribute should be there on which you want to call this function whenever tapped.

You don't need to link button to this method by yourself, `android:onClick` attribute does it for you. If you want to link that button to this function by yourself then you will have to give an `id` to that button using `android:id="@+id/button_send"` and then link in this way:

```
Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
           sendMessage(v);
     }
});
```