# Fragment onClickListener Not registering Click

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I've gone through all the search results on SO and I can't find one that solves my issue. I have a fragment and I am trying to use an ImageButton to close the fragment. But my onClickListener will not register a click. I placed a break-point on the line and it was never hit.

```
ImageButton closeButton;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    if (getArguments().getBoolean("invert") == true) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_inverted_header_and_text, container, false);
    }else {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_header_and_text, container, false);
    }
    rootView.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    closeButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

From my research, the way you add a fragment to a view could affect this, so here is the code where I add the fragment.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    headerAndTextFragment hatf = headerAndTextFragment
            .newInstance("Information on GlassFrogg review process",
                        "Here is some information about the review process that you probably didn't actually want to know",
                        true);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.popupContainer, hatf);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using same id 's in both the layouts since you have a single ImageButton defined in the class on which the listener is registered.

Comment: the both have the same id

Comment: This link should give you a better insight of the issue,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inflating two different layouts. Are you sure both the Layout has that ImageButton ? and both have same ID ?

Comment: they both have the  same Id

Comment: Try assigning different IDs and moving the onClick listeners to their respective if-else block.

Answer (score -1):

when you open the fragment, you don't add the fragment to backStack, so when you click to imagebutton, there is no fragment in the backStack to pop.

use this

```
closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME.this).commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: I do add to the back of the stack

Comment: how?

please, have a look at 

`transaction.addToBackStack(null)`

it adds null to backStack

Comment: as well, make sure both layouts have ImageButton with id "closeButton"