# Fragments of view pager needs to be programmed from the main activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using a view pager . I have three fragments in it I added a button in one of them and tried to make a method for it in the fragment class but this doesn't work. I tried after that to put the method in the main Activity class and it worked.

this is my MainActivity code :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        adapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(this);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);


        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText("تعلم");
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.learn, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText("الصفحة الرئيسية");
        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.home, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabThree.setText("التحديات");
        tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.challenges, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tabPosition = tab.getPosition();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.myQuestions:
                //newGame();
                return true;
            case R.id.aboutApp:
                //showHelp();
                return true;
            case R.id.bestStudents:
                //showHelp();
                return true;
            case R.id.myAccount:
                //showHelp();
                return true;
            case R.id.signOut:
                mAuth.signOut();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeneralSignActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if(tabPosition != 1){
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
        else{
            this.finishAffinity();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my fragment code :

```
public static LearnFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    LearnFragment fragment = new LearnFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_learn,container,false);

    return myView;
}
```

**And this is the xml code of the main activity :**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sample_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/color1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_in_toolbar" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/color1">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is the fragment xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mk.playAndLearn.fragment.LearnFragment">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="click3"
    android:text="click me"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> and tried to make a method for it in the fragment class but this
>   doesn't work

If you have added a `Button` to the `Fragment`, then you should initialize the `Button` inside the `Fragment` **with the view prefix** and adding the `Button` inside the `Fragment` layout too. So:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_learn,container,false);
    Button myBtn = myView.findViewById(R.id.thebuttonid);

    // use onClickListener here to handle the button

    return myView;
}
```

I suppose you were handling the `Button` inside the `MainActivity` class which won't probably work.

---

You are handling the `Button` with `onClick` in the xml so, place the current code inside the `Fragment` and outside of `onCreateView` or any other methods:

```
public void click3(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: The button is in the fragment xml not in the main activity

Comment: You were handling the `Button` inside the MainActivity i guess. That's why

Comment: First I tried to handle the button at the fragment class but when it doesn't work I put it in the main activity and then only it worked

Comment: So my answer is correct. Just handle the `Button` and create your methods inside the `Fragment` if you place the `Button` inside the `Fragment`. Simple, right? :)

Comment: When I place the button inside the fragment it doesn't work

Comment: Updated the answer with xml handling.

Comment: The app crashed when I did that

Comment: Can you paste the logcat somewhere that i can see? However, I’d go just like i wrote in the answer by removing android:onClick from xml and handling the `Button` inside the `onCreateView` by adding the view prefix and `setOnClickListener`

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method click3(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'

Comment: This : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments) will answer to your another question but, my first section of the answer for the handling Button inside onCreaterView is the best option in your situation.