# Changing TextView Attributes from button onClick not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, onclick

So I have a xml fragment called fragment_home. Which has 2 buttons and a textview inside cardview. One of the button (tries to) change the value in the textview. On both the buttons I have an **onClick**. The **tools:context** for the fragment is set to **.MainActivity**. I also have a extend Fragment class which is associated with the xml fragment.

Whenever I try to call anything to change the TextView attributes such as setText,setTextSize I get an exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick`

If I do not have setText, setTextSize, the onClick works.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int textViewData;
private TextView inputDataTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    inputDataTextView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.focus_counter);
}

//onClick For One of the buttons
    public void increaseNumber(View view) {
    textViewData++;
    // Crashes When I have This. Doesn't crash when I comment this.
    inputDataTextView.setTextSize(60);
    // Crashes When I have this. Doesn't crash when I comment this.
    inputDataTextView.setText(String.valueOf(textViewData);

    Toast.makeText(this, "TextView Value = " + textViewData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I feel like It's something to do with my fragment and activity. But I just do not know what the problem is. As soon as I call anything related to the textview in the onClick the app crashes. And the textview in the xml is set to 0 initially and when I increase the number, it increases, so thats working.
Thanks for the help!!

HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private int textViewData;
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

private TextView inputDataTextView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    inputDataTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.focus_counter);

    return view;
}

public void increaseNumber(View view) {
    textViewData++;
    //inputDataTextView.setText("t");
    inputDataTextView.setText(String.valueOf(inputViewData));
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Focus Vale = " + inputViewData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Show us your fragment layout.

Comment: @Jason I have updated the post

Comment: There is no `android:onClick="increaseNumber"` in your layout!!!

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault, I had to change some stuff before I post anything here inorder to protect my project. I have updated the XML file with the correct method name. I tested the onclick without the set.Text and it works fine, when I put that in it crashes.

Comment: Pls post your full log at error

Comment: @Jason Updated Post

Comment: @Jason Updated Post with some debug Info

Comment: Do you have `android:onClick` attribute in your fragment or activity layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `inputDataTextView` is null because its in fragment but your instantiating it from MainActivity, which is wrong. Move both the onClick methods and view to the fragment java code.

**Edit** copy theses codes from MainActivity to HomeFragment before onCreateView:

```
private int textViewData;
private TextView inputDataTextView;
```

Then these inside onCreateView before the return statement:

```
 inputDataTextView= 
   (TextView)findViewById(R.id.focus_counter);
```

Then these method inside your fragment:

```
 public void increaseNumber(View view) {
 textViewData++;
inputDataTextView.setTextSize(60);
inputDataTextView.setText(String.valueOf(textViewData);
Toast.makeText(this, "TextView Value = " + textViewData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}

It should work now

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but how can I do that with code??

Comment: I do have HomeFragment class which extends Fragment. Currently it has nothing on it. So if I want to do onClick in fragment class what must I do? Right now I just changed the tools:context in XML to .HomeFragment and did everything that I did in mainactivity in the fragment class and I am getting the same error.

Comment: Ok I have done as presented and now I am getting Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method increaseNumber(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'focus_plus_button'

 I have also changed tools:context=".HomeFragment" in fragment XML file. Basically I don't think the Fragment class and Fragment XML file are being associated together. But I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Updated Post with fragment class

Comment: Remove the tools:context from xml

Comment: I am getting the same error as before:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method increaseNumber(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'focus_plus_button'. How would you add in buttons inside fragment xml and do the background work related to it in the fragment class? Just wondering because I feel like I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271637/8714139

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for the help my friend!!! I used the above method!!!