# Use XML onClick field to call function in DrawingView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm developing an application in android studio. I currently have two parts, a MainActivity and a DrawingView. In the DrawingView is both a Canvas and a Button.

```
<com.jerem.simpledraw.DrawingView
    android:id="@+id/DrawingView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="554dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    app:exampleColor="#33b5e5"
    app:exampleDimension="24sp"
    app:exampleDrawable="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    app:exampleString="Hello, DrawingView" />

<Button
    android:text="Refresh"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="refreshCallback"/>
```

Above is the layout file for the drawing view. I want the button, when pressed, to call the method "refreshCallback", which is in the class DrawingView.

[However, this warns me that it cannot find the method in the MainActivity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPC0X.png)

I want to call a method in the DrawingView, not in the Main Activity. How can I fix this?

EDIT: I am updating to include the entire DrawingView class. I want to refresh the page.

```
package com.jerem.simpledraw;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class DrawingView extends View
{
//Constant
private int Colour = 0xFF000000;
private int screen_width;
private int screen_height;

//Drawing Var
private Canvas drawCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
private Path drawPath;
private Paint drawPaint;
private Paint canvasPaint;

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
    super(context, attributeSet);
    setupDrawing();
    setupUI();
}

private void setupUI() {

}

private void setupDrawing() {
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();

    drawPaint.setColor(Colour);

    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

private void handelAction(int action, int x, int y){
    switch(action) {
        case 0:
            drawPath.moveTo(x, y);
            break;
        case 2:
            drawPath.lineTo(x, y);
            break;
        case 1:
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            break;
    }
    {
        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    System.out.println(event.getAction());
    handelAction(event.getAction(), (int) x, (int) y);
    return true;
}

public void refreshCallback(View v){
    System.out.println("Refresh Command Sent");
    this.setupDrawing();
}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14663503/3210173 maybe this can help you

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. I've read that question, and it doesn't help unfortunately because the method I want to call is not static, and doesn't work inside main activity.

Comment: Can your share DrawingView class

Comment: I have done thanks

Comment: plz follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or if you have done it differently, answer you own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is `onclick` only tries to find the method that the current class is in which is using it. You can do this if you want, follow the steps :-

MainActivity:

```
public void callRefreshCallback(View v){
   (new DesignView()).refreshCallback(v);
}
```

DesignView:

```
public static void refreshCallback(View v){
//dosomething.
}
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
android:onClick="callRefreshCallback"
```

Comment: Please, is there any way to do this where refershCallback is not static? I cannot do what I want with a static method

Comment: simple `new DrawingView().refreshCallback()`, if you dont have any instance of `DrawingView` in `MainActivity`.

Comment: Drawing view is already created through the code setContentView(R.layout.sample_drawing_view);    If I create a new DrawingView, will that not mess things up?

Comment: Using Drawing view object you can call that method.

Comment: Its not producing instance of `DrawingView` its just setting your `sample_drawing_view.xml` to `MainActivity`.

Comment: Hey, if I create it in this way what do I pass to the (Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet), parameters?

Comment: define one more constructor in `DrawingView` as `public DrawingView(Context context)` and then write `(new DesignView(getApplication.context())).refreshCallback(v);`

Answer (score 0):

You can only call the activity's methods through the xml `onClick`. Therefore, you need a method in your `MainActivity` to pass the function call to the sibling view. If you're wondering why this is, consider this: How should the runtime decide which of the current views' methods should be called when the user clicks the button?

EDIT: Today I learned that it is in fact possible to refer to a static method in your activity class through `onClick`. If you intent to use non-static methods of your activity, you shouldn't declare the method as static, (and vice versa, I suppose).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Is there any way to get the CURRENT INSTANCE of the Drawing View in the main activity? findViewbyId seems to just return a static reference

Comment: Do you change the current instance somewhere? If you do, you should either give the new instance the same id as the old instance, or save the reference to the new instance. If not, findViewById should be enough.

Comment: It is created through the code setContentView(R.layout.sample_drawing_view);   When I use findViewByID, I cannot access variables or use any method that is not static

Comment: The variables are marked as private, so that explains why you can't access them. How exactly are you trying to access the methods, and which of them are you trying to access? I'd think the instance returned by findViewById would be the one where you can access the non-static methods.

Comment: Try with this.getParent().findViewById(...)

Comment: I made the variables public, and tried drawing WHITE over the canvas. I get this error http://i.imgur.com/h72hYwF.png

Comment: This is an error related to calling from a static context

Comment: So it's not just that you used the British spelling for ```drawColor```? Also, did you declare the ```MainWindow ```'s ```refreshCallback``` as static?

Comment: It's not, but thanks for pointing out the typo. Now it has no error, but the function doesn't do anything. Also, no I didn't - why would I?

Comment: This seems to be turning into an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You might want to make a separate question about what you're struggling with now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in Activity class.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_drawing_view);
        DrawingView drawingView = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.DrawingView);
        Button buttonRefresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRefresh);
        buttonRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawingView.refreshCallback(view);
            }
        });
}
```