# Button working only on second click

Tags: java, android, button

I have a simple, but annoying problem:

In my fragment, I have a button which should open another activity (intent) on click. However I have to click the button twice, and only the second time it's opening the activity.
Here is the xml layout of the button:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go!"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:id="@+id/bt_SignIn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />
```

And here is the code for onClick:

```
public void login(View view){
bt_SignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_SignIn);
     bt_SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Frontpage.class);
                    startActivity(i);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You have defined `onClick` in XML as well as registering button `onClick` inside event function ? Use one option and as @Mattia suggested in the answer register it programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the onClick listener for the button twice. You're declaring the onClick in the XML so your method can just be.

```
public void login(View view){
     Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Frontpage.class);
     startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid to use `onClick` directly in the XML, it's a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5400492/2837959).

Remove `onClick` from the XML:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go!"
    android:id="@+id/bt_SignIn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />
```

put this code in the `onCreate` of your `Activity`:

```
bt_SignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_SignIn);
bt_SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Frontpage.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you defining Onclick listener for btn_signIn again? As you already define in your xml login method will call on button click.

Use only below code.

```
public void login(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Frontpage.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because of thee fact that in the function defined in xml you are setting the listener for the button. Do it from either the JAVA code or from the xml code.

This shall suffice

```
public void login(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Frontpage.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

What was happening earlier was that on the first click the function defined in the xml was getting invoked which inturn was setting the listener for the button, and so on the next click your activity was getting triggered

Answer (score 1):

**Change your `login(View view)` method as follows**

```
public void login(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Frontpage.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

**Or much better put your code inside `onCreate()` method**

```
bt_SignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_SignIn);
bt_SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Frontpage.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

and remove `onClick` from your layout

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go!"
    android:id="@+id/bt_SignIn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />
```