# Set onClick in xml for custom view in android in't work on some version

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I create custom view and use it in some xml activity then set `android:onClick="buttonOnClick"`. I defined `buttonOnClick` as `public` and write it in its activity and set `tools:context`.

Activity.java

```
 public void buttonOnClick(View view) {
        validate(view);
    }
```

layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...
    tools:context="com.test.myapp.Activity">

   <com.test.myapp.GifImageViewComp
      ....
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"  />
```

it's working on `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP` but in other OS version, custom view xml onclick attribute try to find handler from view class instead of activity.

I don't want use implementation of onClick  or setOnClickListener on every view, i want use onClick in layout of activity

Comment: instead, use onClickListener in class, and using the id of your customView, call onClick()

Comment: Did you set `android:clickable="true"` ??? .For good Practice use onClickListener

Comment: yes, set `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: @MohammadJavad FYI, `android:onClick` won't work in FRAGMENT

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, i don't use Fragment , but its work in android 5 or higher

Answer (score 1):

> It's just not clear the relationship between a button in your xml and
>   a method in your activity that reacts to the click events unless you
>   explicitly see it defined in your Java file. With the android:onClick
>   approach you can even forget that you have a button in your layout or
>   which is the method that is handling its onClick event.

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400234/in-android-is-it-better-applying-an-onclicklistener-or-use-androidonclick)**

You should use **[OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)** instead of **android:onClick** .

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is
>   clicked.

This method takes the reference to the Listener and registers a callback to be invoked when the View is clicked.

**FYI**

Make sure you set **`android:clickable="true"`** in XML . you should specify **this attribute** .

```
<com.test.myapp.GifImageViewComp
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"  />
```